# modify lines when find specified string

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which looks like this

```
ABC
     2   3   4
     7   9   4
     1   2   5
ABC
     13  11  17
     2   1   1
ABC
     7   9   14
     5   8   2
     9   9   9
     7   1   2
```

and I want to print at the end of each "ABC" values the word "END" so the file will be like this

```
ABC
     2   3   4
     7   9   4
END  1   2   5
ABC
     13  11  17
END  2   1   1
ABC
     7   9   14
     5   8   2
     9   9   9
END  7   1   2
```

I tried a lot but I didn't solve it, so can any one help here.

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ certain that the `END` string should be prepended to an existing line rather than added on a line by itself?

Comment: yes sir this is excatly what i need !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk '/^ABC/ && pre { print dpre ORS $0; pre=""; next }
                   { if(pre) print pre; pre=dpre=$0; sub(/ {0,4}/, "END ", dpre) }
END{ if(pre) print dpre }' infile
```

first block will be executed only if a line starts with *`ABC`*  string and when a temporary variable *`pre`* also was set otherwise next block will be executed.

the `END{...}` block will be executed only once and after end of all.

for the first line of course still *`pre`* variable doesn't set yet, so second block will be executed and it does following:

- if there was things inside `pre` print it first `if(pre) print pre` (with this we delay printing of previous line in order to check if next line starts with `ABC` or not, because we need to add `END` in front of that line)
- then we copy that line into say two separate variables `pre` and `dpre` (one would be untouched (later we need print it untouched) and for the another one in `sub(/ {0,3}/,"END ", dpre)` we are prepending the `END` string into `dpre`.

  *Note that with  `{0,4}` (zero or maximum 4 spaces; 4 is obtained from the length of `END<SPC>`) we ensure that the `END` string will be always prepended as well as preventing truncating the original line value if there was no spaces at all.*

---

Below you can trace each iteration of the command for your own understanding:

- **REPEAT**
- Read a line; Is it start with *`ABC`* (`/^ABC/`)?

  - **no**; then do nothing and next block will be executed; go to **2<sup>nd</sup>-Block**
  - **yes**; Is `pre` was set?

    - **yes**, then do these

      - print content of the `dpre` variable then a single newline `ORS` and then current line itself
      - empty variable `pre=""` and jump to **REPEAT** because of `next` statement tell that.
    - **no**; then do nothing and next block will be executed; go to **2<sup>nd</sup>-Block**
- **2<sup>nd</sup>-Block**

  - is `pre` was set?

    - **yes**; do these

      - print `pre` it's set in "`if(pre) print pre`";
      - update current line into both variables `pre=dpre=$0`;
      - prepend *`END`*  string for `dpre`.
    - **no**; do these

      - update current line into both variables `pre=dpre=$0`;
      - prepend *`END`*  string for `dpre`.
- if END of file; print last state of the `dpre` variable if it was set, else jump to **REPEAT**.
- finish

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF == 1 { sub(/^   /,"END",prev) }
NR > 1 { print prev }
{ prev = $0 }
END { sub(/^   /,"END",prev); print prev }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ABC
     2   3   4
     7   9   4
END  1   2   5
ABC
     13  11  17
END  2   1   1
ABC
     7   9   14
     5   8   2
     9   9   9
END  7   1   2
```

Answer (score 4):

`POSIX sed` with autoprinting of pattern space shut off (`-n`)

```
sed -ne '
  /ABC/!{x;1!p;$!d;}
  x;1!s/^ \{0,3\}/END&/p
  ${x;/ABC/p;}
'  file
```

```
ABC
     2   3   4
     7   9   4
END  1   2   5
ABC
     13  11  17
END  2   1   1
ABC
     7   9   14
     5   8   2
     9   9   9
END  7   1   2
```

---

Stretching out the above sed code and commented.

```
sed -ne '
  # if we see a non boundary line...
  /ABC/!{
    x;           # store it n retrieve prev line
    1!p;         # print the prev line if not first (obviously)
    $!d;         # printed prev so go back n read next line unless we are @eof(for which see below...)
  }
  x;                  # retrieve prev
  1!s/^ \{0,3\}/END&/p; # add marker
  ${x;/ABC/p;}
  # To account for a trailing ABC
'  file
```

Answer (score 4):

Another `sed` approach:

```
1 {                     # First line of data.
        h;              # Hold current line.
        d;              # Skip to next cycle.
}

/^ABC$/ {               # An "ABC" line.
        x;              # Swap in previous line.
        s/.../END/p;    # Add "END" at start of line & print.
        d;              # Skip to next cycle.
}

x;      # Swap current and previous lines.

# Previous line now in pattern space,
# current line in hold space.

$ {                     # Last line of data.
        p;              # Print previous line.
        g;              # Get current line from hold space.
        s/.../END/;     # Add "END" at start of line.
}

# (implicit print)
```

This keeps the current line in the hold space until it has read the next line. It's not until then that we know if we need to add `END` to the line, or not, before printing it.  It's only when we get to the very last line of input data that we know we need to add `END` to the current line and can print both the previous and current line in the same cycle.

My approach assumes that the input data contains at least two lines of input, and that the last line is not `ABC`.

On the command line:

```bsh
sed -e '1{h;d;}' -e '/^ABC$/{x;s/.../END/p;d;}' -e 'x' -e '${p;g;s/.../END/;}'
```

Comment: @ Kusalananda has it ever crossed your mind to write a comprehensive cookbook on shell programming, which would comprise your and some others contributions here. It could be runaway chart topper. I can give the title name: "The Joy (ananda) of Shell programming" or "The Proficient (kushal) Shell Programmer".

Comment: @guest_7 That's a project for when I retire. Thanks for the compliment.

Answer (score 2):

**Perl** can be used in this scenario and due to its powerful regex capabilities can sort it out in a true one-liner.

`perl` in slurp mode `-0777` with autoprint current record turned ON `-p`, we examine all lines that are followed by ABC line or eof.
In both scenarios slip in the string "END" at the beginning, overwriting upto 3 leading whitespace characters.

```
perl -0777pe '
  s/^(?!ABC)\h{0,3}(?=.*\n(?:ABC|\z))/END/mg;
' file
```

Study of the regex:

- Look for a line that doesn't begin w/ ABC `^(?!ABC)`
- Has none to 3 whitespace(atleast) in the beginning `\h{0,3}`
- From this vantage point point if we are able to see till the end of current line `(?=.*\n(?:ABC|\z)` and from there on the next line which begins with ABC or it's the eof.
- Perform the substitution. Understand that lookarounds do not consume data but are there to assert the match locations.